# Empty post error

Tags: php, jquery, pdo

I need to make my script detect, if post is empty so that it will post error.
Right now, when my post is empty, it posts all the results.

my code

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `media`.`id`, `media`.`title` FROM `media` WHERE `media`.`title` LIKE :keywords");

$keywords = (isset($_POST['keywords']) === true) ? $_POST['keywords'] : '';
$query->bindValue(':keywords', '%' . $keywords . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

$arr = array();
$query->execute();
while( $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $arr[] = array( "id" => $row["id"], "title" => $row["title"]);
}
echo json_encode( $arr );

?>
```

and my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search").click(function(){
        $.post("search.php", { keywords: $(".keywords").val() }, function(data){
            $("div#search").empty()
            $.each(data, function(){
                $("div#search").append("- <a href='#?id=" + this.id + "'>" + this.title + "</a><br>");
            });
        }, "json");
    });
});
```

Comment: Can I just say that I cringe whenever I see constructs like `isset($_POST['keywords']) === true`. People seem to be afraid of any boolean expression not involving the keywords `true` and `false`...

Comment: well, this _is_ php.  for all we know, `isset` in a boolean context casts to banana.

Comment: @Eevee [Ook!](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/ook.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
if(empty( $keywords ) ) {
     // Show some error
}
else{

   // your search code here ...
}
```

**but it's preferred to do the check in the JS too before posting**

Comment: Validation should *always* be done on the server-side. JS *as well* might be nice, but you should never rely on the client-side being nice and preventing "bad" behaviour for you.

Comment: I didn't say he should rely on it but I mean additionally doing it to avoid server-side processing for no reason.

Comment: Fair enough. It didn't come across that way with your big bold text saying "it's preferred"; you might want to edit your answer in case someone gets the wrong idea. :)

Comment: I add "too" :D to the bold section :D